# ¿Cómo puedo poner la fecha actual en un input sin que se borre con un reset?

Tags: javascript, html5

No he podido hacer que en un campo quede la fecha actual sin que lo afecte un botón de reset. Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("fechaSubCampana");
var meses = new Array("enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre");
var fecha = new Date();
input.value = (fecha.getDate() + " de " + meses[fecha.getMonth()] + " del " + fecha.getFullYear());
var esto = input.value = (fecha.getDate() + " de " + meses[fecha.getMonth()] + " del " + fecha.getFullYear());
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="fechaSubCampana" value="script: esto;" placeholder="" disabled>
```

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</button>
```

Pongo a modo de ejemplo el valor del atributo value. Tengo este formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al pulsar el botón "Limpiar" se borra la fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que te ocurre. ¿Podrías especificar más? He probado ese código y el boton de reset no te afecta en nada.

Comment: Cual es la pregunta? No se entiende

Comment: Que es lo que quieres realizar? probe tu codigo y funciona segun lo que deseas. Explicate mejor

Comment: Creo que quiere que el input con la fecha no se borre al pulsar sobre el boton `type="reset"` del formulario.

Comment: Disculpen el no explicarme bien.  Necesito que el input con la fecha no se borre al momento de pulsar el botón de reset.

Comment: pero todavia no entiendo que es lo que te falla o algo asi

Comment: Lo que quiere es que no se le borre un campo al clickar en un botón type="reset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible, tienes que crear tu una funcion donde llames al reset y enseguida setear la fecha de nuevo

```js
setFecha();

function setFecha(){
  var input = document.getElementById("fechaSubCampana");
    var meses = new Array("enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre");
    var fecha = new Date();
    input.value = (fecha.getDate() + " de " + meses[fecha.getMonth()] + " del " + fecha.getFullYear());
    var esto = input.value = (fecha.getDate() + " de " + meses[fecha.getMonth()] + " del " + fecha.getFullYear());
}


function limpiar(){
  document.getElementById("form").reset();
  setFecha();
}
```

```html
<form id="form">

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="fechaSubCampana" placeholder="" disabled>

<button type="button" value="reset" onclick="limpiar();" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</button>

</form>
```

Comment: ¡Gracias @Lato!, ya me funciona como quiero. Saludos